# get the key value from javascript object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this object:

```
"{"logEntries":[],"value":"-8","text":"Europe","enabled":true}"
```

how do i get the value of the "value" key in jQuery with minimum code?. 
in this case "-8".

Comment: You have double quotes inside double quotes.  You should wrap it in single quotes, or better remove the quotes entirely, it doesn't need to be a string.

Comment: @Rocket I can't remove it because this string is a value of a hidden field that is created dynamically by one of Telerik controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = '{"logEntries":[],"value":"-8","text":"Europe","enabled":true}';
obj = $.parseJSON(obj);
console.log(obj.value);
```

You had double quotes inside double quotes, you can't do that, you need to wrap it in single quotes.

Also, you don't need the quotes here in the first place, just make an object, not a string, so you don't to parse.

```
var obj = {"logEntries":[],"value":"-8","text":"Europe","enabled":true};
console.log(obj.value);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest :

```
var myObject = '{"logEntries":[], "value":"-8", "text":"Europe", "enabled":true}';
alert($.parseJSON(myObject).value);
```

Comment: This will throw an error as `$.parseJSON(myObject)` is null. Edit: never mind. I see  you corrected myObject.

Comment: I have tested these 2 lines (copy/paste), and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = {"logEntries":[],"value":"-8","text":"Europe","enabled":true}

var valueProperty = x.value
```